# Change search form behaviour

Tags: php, javascript, search, uitextfield, search-form

1. How do I separately style the text inside the search field (on the right)?
   I want to have light grey color when there's a default text (SEARCH) and I want a black color when a person inputs a word.

   - I tried wrapping the function inside the new `div` tag but no use, it gives me a PHP error.
   - I used FireBug to track the problem but couldn't figure it out on my own.
2. When you write something in the search (don't press Enter) and then click away, the text you wrote stays inside a search field. What can I do to get the effect so that whenever you click away from the search field, it resets to a default word (SEARCH in this case)?

   - I tried playing with `onblur` and `onfocus` but I don't know what to change to get a desired behavior.
   - I also used a code for form reset but that just gives me the button that you have to click to reset to default text.
3. If the answer to the second question is too complex, I'd like to get the following instead:

   - When the site loads - search field says SEARCH.
   - When you input something (don't press Enter) and click away, the text that you input stays BUT...
   - ... When you click that search field again, the previously input text is completely selected so that if you start writing something new, the search field shows only the new text. (At the moment, if you click the filed after clicking away, your new text is just added to the text you input before it).

Comment: PHP doesn't care what you do with the contents of the HTML, the error was most likely due to a syntax error in the code. If you post what you did when you added the `<div>` we can let you know where that was.

Comment: Well I tried wrapping `onfocus="if (this.value == '<?php echo $search_text; ?>') {this.value = '';}"` inside a `div` with an ID because I thought that would give me a chance to target the text that is being input. I can style all the text (default and input) by changing `#st` but I can't target only one of those two.

Comment: I removed your dead link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for both #1 and #2 for me (tested in FF, not sure about IE).

The `onclick` checks if the default value is still in the search field, if it is, it gets cleared out and the user can type something in black text.

When they click away, the `onblur` event fires and checks if the default value is present. If it isn't, the value gets reset and changed to a light gray.

```
<input type="text" name="search" value="SEARCH" style="color: #DDDDDD;"
    onclick="javascript: if( this.value == 'SEARCH') { this.value = ''; this.style.color = '#000000'; } "
    onblur="javascript: if( this.value != 'SEARCH') { this.value = 'SEARCH'; this.style.color = '#DDDDDD'; }" />
```

Comment: That's awesome, thanks! I played with the existing code and your code and found that when I add `onfocus` function, the first input is grey in color and you get black input after you click away and then back inside a field. Doesn't matter as I removed `onfocus` but that seemed interesting to me. :D

A question - can you maybe see what I messed up so that the search function doesn't work anymore? :/
I obviously deleted something and now when I search for a word it stays on the same page.

Comment: Searching works for me when I press enter - But what might be happening is the `onblur` event is firing before the form gets submitted, which will reset the input back to 'SEARCH'

Comment: Try typing "GOA" to a search form. The search result should only show the lower post. Instead it shows both posts and just changes the address to `http://thefalljourneyindia.iblogger.org/?st=goa`.

Comment: Your form is set to `method=GET`, which is why you get the URL change. If you're expecting a POST parameter, change the form method. Otherwise, the form is correctly putting the `st` field into the URL.

Comment: OK, I'll have to read about it elsewhere to understand completely what you mean and will ask a new question if I can't figure it out after that.
Thank you for all your help.